# Is there an alternate way to write the sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]

I have 3 tables - class table, student table, studentclass table

From the help of these tables I need to write a query that tells us about the student who has not joined any class

I have written a query that is working, but I was wondering if there is an alternative and a simpler way to write the query to get the desired result

```
SELECT s.studentName, c.className 
FROM student s 
LEFT JOIN studentClass sc 
ON sc.studentId = s.studentId 
LEFT JOIN classes c 
ON sc.classId = c.classId 
WHERE c.className IS NULL
```

Comment: Your `where` should check if the key used in the `join` is `null`, in this case `c.classId`, as that is what proves there was no match. A `null` in `className` or any other field might just mean there was a match on the key but that particular field was `null` for whatever reason; it's ambiguous, not conclusive.

Comment: You don't need the class name table

Comment: @underscore_d can you please explain with the help of code

Comment: @JamesJenkins can you please explain with the help of code

Comment: @user3732711 No. I said to replace `className` with `classId` in your `where` clause, which is as simple as it gets and does not warrant illustration in my view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check if the student's id exists or not in `studentclass`.
 
With NOT IN:

```
select * 
from student 
where studentid not in (select studentid from studentclass)
```

or with NOT EXISTS:

```
select s.* 
from student s
where not exists (
  select 1 from studentclass
  where studentid = s.studentid
)
```

Comment: Wouldn't you use an `EXIST` predicate to check for existence?

Comment: I added a NOT EXISTS solution too.